# How do I use Pipe(filter) for the time in angular 5 project

Tags: angular, datetime, time, pipe, angular5

I am working on an angular 5 project and I am successful in date Pipe but I don't know how to use Pipe(filter) for the time in my angular project.

This is my component.ts file

```
import { LazyLoadEvent } from 'primeng/components/common/lazyloadevent';
import { ManageRadioViewComponent } from './manage-radio-view.component';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-manage-radio',
 templateUrl: './manage-radio.component.html',
 providers: [
 DatePipe
  ]
})
export class ManageRadioComponent extends AppComponentBase implements OnInit 
{

 @ViewChild('viewModal') viewModal: ManageRadioViewComponent;
 @ViewChild('tt') dataTable: Table;

 constructor(_injector: Injector, private _dataService: DataService, private 
 spinner: NgxSpinnerService, private dp: DatePipe ) { 
 super(_injector);
}

 public cols: any[] = [
   { field: "startDate" , header: 'Start Date', type: this.dp },
   { field: "endDate", header: 'End Date', type: this.dp },
   { field: 'startTime', header: 'Start Time'},
   { field: 'endTime', header: 'End Time'}
  ]
```

The 'Start Date' and 'End Date' works fine but I can't find a way to Pipe the 'Start Time' and 'End Time'.

Below is my component.html file.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <tr>
                  <th>Actions</th>
                  <th *ngFor="let col of cols" pResizableColumn>{{col.header}}</th>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
              <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-data>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="view(data.id)">
                      <i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp; View
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <td *ngFor="let col of cols">{{col.type ? col.type.transform(data[col.field], col.arg1, col.arg2, col.arg3, col.arg4) : data[col.field]}}</td>
                </tr>
              </ng-template>
```

Please help out.

Comment: normally you use pipes like this `<span>{{some.sort.of.data | somePipe}}</span>` you dont have to inject pipe into component.

Comment: @Antoniossss Yes but am using the cols.field format above. Do you know how to use it in my format?